# from PyQt4 import QtGui ImportError: cannot import name 'QtGui'

Tags: python, qt

I'm new to UI design using qt - I installed qt and the pyqt4 wrapper.

I have this simply 'hello world' type script here:

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtGui


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    w.resize(250, 150)
    w.move(300, 300)
    w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Yet I get this error:

C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/me/Desktop/python/testqt.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Leo/Desktop/python/testqt.py", line 2, in 
    from PyQt4 import QtGui
ImportError: cannot import name 'QtGui'

The existing answers on SE do not seem to help. What causes this?

Answer (score 1):

**In my case I installed the PyQt4-4.11.4-gpl-Py3.4-Qt4.8.7-x32.exe and it worked**

-- previously I had installed PyQt4-4.11.4-gpl-Py3.4-Qt4.8.7-x64.exe and got the error reported above.